# How to change default app for all files of particular file type through terminal in OS X?

Tags: macos, file-association

How can I change the default app for all files of a particular file type through the Terminal in OS X?

Comment: **Not a dupe,** even though I kind of answered it there. Sorry about that.

Comment: For power use, I like the [accepted answer](http://superuser.com/a/341429/84988) under a more recent Super User question, [Is there a faster way to change default apps associated with file types on OS X?](http://superuser.com/q/305498/84988). For simplicity, I like [Daniel's answer below](http://superuser.com/a/273770/84988).

Answer (score 84):

I have a simpler way. You'll want [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) if you don't already have it:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

## Install duti:

```
brew install duti
```

Now you need to find the id of the app you want to use, and assign it to the extension you want to use it for. In this example, I already use Brackets for `*.sh` and I want to also use it for `*.md` files instead of xcode.

## Get the default app id for `.sh` files:

```
duti -x sh

output:
  Brackets.app
  /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/brackets/1.6/Brackets.app
  io.brackets.appshell
```

The last line is the id.

## Use this app id for all `.md` files:

```
duti -s io.brackets.appshell .md all
```

Comment: Would upvote this 50 times if I could.  Great info.  Worked like a charm for me in El Capitan.

Comment: Working in Sierra too. Extra tip: UTIs are a pain, but you can use "mdls -name kMDItemContentType <file>" to find the UTI for a given file (and therefore extension).

Comment: If you haven't already associated an app with something this way but know the name of your the app, you can do `osascript -e 'id of app "$appName"'` to get the id of any app installed on your system

Comment: Just for the reference: combining tip from @GrayedFox with duti: `duti -s $(osascript -e 'id of app "Visual Studio Code"') .md all`

Comment: And by the way, the id for Visual Studio Code is `com.microsoft.VSCode`

Comment: Have PhpStorm handle all PHP files: `duti -s com.jetbrains.PhpStorm .php all`

Comment: In my case, I was trying to ensure that Sublime Text (on macOS) was associated with many extensions, so I did `for ext in php js json yml md sh zsh html; do; duti -s "osascript -e 'id of app \"Sublime Text\"'" ".$ext" all; done`

Comment: Blessings be upon you. I'm getting a nervous tic because every time I double-click an .mp3 file I get Music instead of VLC, despite my having set VLC as the default within the past 3 days. Now I've put a script in my .bash_profile :-)

Answer (score 20):

Edit `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`.

Add an entry under `LSHandlers`, containing the UTI (key `LSHandlerContentType`, e.g. `public.plain-text`) and application bundle identifier (`LSHandlerRoleAll`, e.g. `com.macromates.textmate`).

It looks like this in *Property List Editor*:

[image]
[image]

To do this from the command line, use `defaults` or `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`. Both have extensive manpages.

For example to open all `.plist` files using `Xcode`:

> `defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers -array-add '{ LSHandlerContentType = "com.apple.property-list"; LSHandlerRoleAll = "com.apple.dt.xcode"; }'`

Of course, you'd need to make sure there's not already another entry for the UTI `com.apple.property-list` already in there.

Here's a more complete script that'll remove existing entries for a UTI and add a new one. It can only handle `LSHandlerContentType`, and will always set `LSHandlerRoleAll`, and has hard-coded bundle IDs instead of parameters. Other than that, it should work quite well.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PLIST="$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist"
BUDDY=/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy

# the key to match with the desired value
KEY=LSHandlerContentType

# the value for which we'll replace the handler
VALUE=public.plain-text

# the new handler for all roles
HANDLER=com.macromates.TextMate

$BUDDY -c 'Print "LSHandlers"' $PLIST >/dev/null 2>&1
ret=$?
if [[ $ret -ne 0 ]] ; then
        echo "There is no LSHandlers entry in $PLIST" >&2
        exit 1
fi

function create_entry {
        $BUDDY -c "Add LSHandlers:$I dict" $PLIST
        $BUDDY -c "Add LSHandlers:$I:$KEY string $VALUE" $PLIST
        $BUDDY -c "Add LSHandlers:$I:LSHandlerRoleAll string $HANDLER" $PLIST
}

declare -i I=0
while [ true ] ; do
        $BUDDY -c "Print LSHandlers:$I" $PLIST >/dev/null 2>&1
        [[ $? -eq 0 ]] || { echo "Finished, no $VALUE found, setting it to $HANDLER" ; create_entry ; exit ; }

        OUT="$( $BUDDY -c "Print 'LSHandlers:$I:$KEY'" $PLIST 2>/dev/null )"
        if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then 
                I=$I+1
                continue
        fi

        CONTENT=$( echo "$OUT" )
        if [[ $CONTENT = $VALUE ]] ; then
                echo "Replacing $CONTENT handler with $HANDLER"
                $BUDDY -c "Delete 'LSHandlers:$I'" $PLIST
                create_entry
                exit
        else
                I=$I+1 
        fi
done
```

Comment: The easiest way is probably to `x=~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist; plutil -convert xml1 $x; open -a TextEdit $x` and copy and paste those LSHandlers entries. To get the bundle identifier you can do `osascript -e 'bundle identifier of (info for (path to app "TextEdit"))'`.

Comment: @Lri In a way, yes, but this question is specifically about the command line. I figured that TextEdit (or Property List Editor / Xcode) doesn't qualify; I just copied over that part with Property List Editor from my other answer for illustration purposes. Useful remark on the bundle identifier.

Comment: Credit to Daniel, I borrowed from this for [an answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/49998/8546) to a question in Ask Different, [Can Finder and the “open” command treat files with .sh or other typical extensions just like .command files?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/20118/8546).

Comment: If there *does* exist an alternative entry for the UTI, would you agree that "command line removal of a single dictionary from an array may be unnecessarily difficult"?

Comment: @GrahamPerrin It is *unnecessarily* difficult because `defaults` doesn't seem to be capable to do it, and it requires a few `PlistBuddy` calls. But it's possible to do it in a reusable shell script.

Comment: Side note: the "unnecessarily difficult" quote was from from the [first edition](http://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/49998/1) of an answer to a different question.

Comment: I guess `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` doesn't exist on Mac OS X 11.

Answer (score 0):

dutis is a wrapper of duti, providing an interactive way to set default applications in command line.

You can set default applications using dutis within a few steps:

Waiting for environment checking

[image]

Selecting suffix

[image]

Selecting application UTI

[image]