# OS X open new terminal from command line that works in linux too

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, unix, terminal

I'm creating npm scripts for a node based project, and I would like to create a script that first opens a new terminal, and then executes that command there. I'm using a mac myself, but the other devs might use linux.

Now I want to make a command that is cross env in a way that it works in both environments. I know OS X is based on unix, so one could think because of this there is an easy way to make a cross env shell script that opens terminal.

EDIT: I do not want any mouse clicks. Just a shell script, that opens a new terminal in both os x and linux.

Answer (score 3):

There's no cross-platform command do to that. While macOS uses Unix underneath, the terminal applications under macOS and Linux are completely different, and the user might have different terminals installed. Under macOS, that could be Terminal.app, iTerm2 or others, and under Linux you could have people running GNOME Terminal, Konsole, Terminator, etc. — or not even running a graphical environment at all. Have you considered that?

The ways to open applications are different among the OSes, too. You have to write separate functionalities for both operating systems.

#### macOS

Under macOS, all you would need to launch Terminal.app and run a script is:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "/path/to/script.sh"'
```

I think you could get the default terminal (if it's not Terminal.app) by inpecting the default file associations, but it's a little cumbersome without third-party tools such as `duti` (Use Homebrew to `brew install duti`), where you'd do:

```
terminal=$(duti -x .command | head -n 1)
osascript -e "tell application \"$terminal\" to do script \"/path/to/script.sh\""
```

But I guess `duti`'s functionality can be reverse-engineered by inspecting [its source code](https://github.com/moretension/duti). For more info, see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/273756/how-to-change-default-app-for-all-files-of-particular-file-type-through-terminal).

You could also create a `.command` file and open that via `open`:

```
touch example.command
echo "echo foo" > example.command
chmod +x example.command
open example.command
```

This would automatically select the user-defined terminal emulator.

#### Linux

Under Linux, usually you can access the default terminal with `x-terminal-emulator`:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "/path/to/script"
```

Make sure the script is actually executable (`chmod +x`).